# get number of connections in PHP on a socket

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

Is there a way in PHP to grab the number of clients that are connected to a socket?

would calling an exec command like `netstat -n | grep -c 7778` be a smart way to do this?

Comment: Will this number of clients have any impact on the code flow? i.e. will be used as a condition for something?

Comment: no - I need to be able to report how many people are connected....as close to realtime as possible if it won't have any large processing impact, but I'm really w/ up to a 30sec refresh.